# Heroku adding 'undefined' to BASE_URL environment variable

Tags: express, heroku, environment-variables, axios, base-url

attempting to deploy a vuejs, express app to heroku. The app displays, but cannot access the api, because heroku seems to add 'undefined' in the middle of the base_url. Everything works locally as expected.

Here is my heroku config var:
`BASE_URL:    https://goore-todos.herokuapp.com/`

Here is the Vuejs component api request:

```
fetchTodo () {
  let uri = process.env.BASE_URL + '/api/all';
  axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
    this.todos = response.data;
  });
},
```

As mentioned, this works locally.

the console shows the following error: 
    VM71:1 GET https://goore-todos.herokuapp.com/undefined/api/all 404 (Not Found)

and the view is empty.

requests to https://goore-todos.herokuapp.com/api/ via Postman work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it looks like process.env.BASE_URL is undefined. As it is undefined, the url you're trying to access is considered to be relative. That means it uses your current domain and appends the path to it.

If your frontend and backend are running on the same domain there is no reason to try to pass the API url as a variable as you can just use relative URLs.

If you want to access the URL via an environment variable it is a bit trickier with a frontend app. The Vue app is running on the user's browser, not on your server so you can't directly access it.

Comment: Using relative urls works. Thanks! I am still wondering how process.env.BASE_URL is undefined when I have it set in heroku and when it works in the local environment reading from .env

Comment: @user2799827 typically environment variables for frontend apps need to be specified when the app is built. When your app is on someone else's browser of course it can't read the environment variable from your server

Comment: @user27 Some JavaScript applications only environment variables at compile time, you may have retrigger a deploy of the app

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and had to go through and hard code all of my URLs with the heroku URL. I tried resetting the config variables in Heroku which had an extra slash at the end, but in the end hard-coding each API call was the only thing that fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).